# Writing a sum function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, function

How can I create a one line function in typescript return like this:

sum(x)(y) -> x+y, e.g sums(2)(4) -> 6

Given that:

```
const result = sum(2)(4); // 6

console.log('Result:', result);
```

I have tried with a way like this:

```
    function sum(x: number, y: number) {
        return x + y;
    }
```

Comment: The function definition is correct, but you call it as `const result = sum(2,4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
const sum = (x: number, y: number): number => x + y;

console.log("sum", sum(1,2))

const sumNested = (x: number) => (y: number): number => x + y;

console.log("sumNested", sumNested(3)(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sum(x){
  return function(y){
    return x + y;
  };
}


const result = sum(2)(4); // 6

console.log('Result:', result);
```

With ES6 arrow functions;

```
let sum = (x) => (y) => x + y;

console.log('Result:', sum(2)(4)); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You must separate your arguments with commas, not parentheses, like so:

```
const result = sum(2, 4);
```

If you really want to use `sum(2)(4)`:

```
function sum(numOne) {
  return function(numTwo) {
    return numOne + numTwo;
  }
}

sum(2)(4) // 6
```

This occurs because the `sum` function returns another function, and the second pair of parentheses (the `(4)` part), executes another function.

This is generally bad practice though, so you are better off using `sum(2, 4)`.

Comment: @SmallPotato Edited answer to address this.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot! I wasn't come up with a function inside another function.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I was come up with the whole thing like below at the beginning:

const result = sum(2, 4);

function sum(x: number, y: number) {
    return x + y;
}

console.log('Result:', result);

but someone just challenge me if I can rewrite a sum function like sum(2)(4) with the expected same output, then I couldn't come up with your suggested answer lol.